# PL/SQL Error ORA-01403: No data found. Not receiving anticipated results

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Basically, I've created a business report (Query) in oracle to extracts information from the FREQUENT_FLYER table, in regards to passengers that have a mileage balance that is >10000 but less than 20000 and that the MileageExpDate is greater than October 1st of 2017.

```
SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, 
F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
WHERE MileageBalance >= 10000 AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= 20000
AND MileageExpDate > '01/OCT/2017';
```

Here, is the result for that query. It's should only return ONE RECORD.
[image]

I'm trying around with stored procedure, and I decided to convert that query into the store procedure

```
--First Stored Procedure--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetMileageBalance 
IS  --Code declaration section--
    --variables to store column values returned from select into
     fPassengerID        VARCHAR2(10);
     pFirst              VARCHAR2(20);
     pLast               VARCHAR2(20);
     fFreqflyernum       NUMBER (10);
     fFreqflyerMileage   NUMBER (7);
     fMileagebalance     NUMBER (7);
     fMileageExpDate     DATE;
     MileageExpDate      DATE;
     MileageStart        NUMBER (7);
     MileageEnd          NUMBER (7);
     MileageBalance      NUMBER (7);

BEGIN --Code execution section
              --executing select into Query assign to variable
              MileageExpDate := '01/OCT/2017';
              MileageStart := 10000;
              MileageEnd :=  20000;
SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE,  
F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
INTO  fPassengerID,  
pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage,fMileagebalance,fMileageExpDate
FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
WHERE MileageBalance >= MileageStart AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= MileageEnd
AND MileageExpDate > MileageExpDate;

--Displaying the results
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CUSTOMER INFORMATION: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  ' ||fPassengerID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('First Name of passenger is:  ' ||pFirst);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Last Name of passenger is:  ' ||pLast);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: ' ||fFreqflyernum);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  ' ||fFreqflyerMileage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  ' ||MileageBalance );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  ' ||MileageExpDate);

END sp_GetMileageBalance;
```

I'm expecting the store procedure to return information based on that one record.
Instead, this is what I get.

```
Procedure SP_GETMILEAGEBALANCE compiled


Error starting at line : 57 in command -
BEGIN sp_GetMileageBalance; END;
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.SP_GETMILEAGEBALANCE", line 29
ORA-06512: at line 1
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch
```

I don't know why I'm getting this result, when I should be getting the same information as I did the query.

Comment: One thing is that your MileageStart in the proc is integer, and in your SQL it's a character.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem:

```
drop table test_table;
create table test_table ( charcol varchar2(10), numcol integer);
insert into test_table select ' 15000',15000 from dual;

select * from test_table where charcol>'10000'; --no record
select * from test_table where charcol>10000; --1 record
```

Comment: Your statement is correct, but wasn't the issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, MileageStart was a variable created within the stored procedure. It is not displayed within the SQL Query at all (scroll up to see for yourself). Also, it is plausible to say that in the SQL query I created, that the value being specified in this case is referred to as a character.

```
 WHERE MileageBalance >= '10000'
```

For some reason, even if I have that "character" in quotation, oracle will still give me that same result.

```
 SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, 
 F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
 FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
 INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
 ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
 WHERE F.MileageBalance >= '10000' AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= 20000
 AND MileageExpDate > '01/OCT/2017';
```

RESULT:
  [First Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcGxI.png)

Same Query, but with the character quotes removed

```
  SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, 
  F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
  FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
  INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
  ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
  WHERE F.MileageBalance >= 10000 AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= 20000
  AND MileageExpDate > '01/OCT/2017';
```

RESULT: [Second Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgb3y.png)

Now, getting back to the store procedure, we need to understand one thing. The reason why these variables are declared/created:

```
 fPassengerID        VARCHAR2(10);
 pFirst              VARCHAR2(20);
 pLast               VARCHAR2(20);
 fFreqflyernum       NUMBER (10);
 fFreqflyerMileage   NUMBER (7);
 fMileagebalance     NUMBER (7);
 fMileageExpDate     DATE;
 MileageExpDate      DATE;
 MileageStart        NUMBER (7);
 MileageEnd          NUMBER (7);
 MileageBalance      NUMBER (7);
```

Is because there are placeholders that store whatever values that are extracted from the tables created in the database (Captain Obvious).

This is what the declared variables are being compared against to...

```
SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE,  
F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
INTO  fPassengerID,  
pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage,fMileagebalance,fMileageExpDate
```

These variables created:

```
              MileageExpDate := '01/OCT/2017';
              MileageStart := 10000;
              MileageEnd :=  20000;
```

Couldn't be utilized, since these variables (although declared) are not referenced by an attribute in any of the tables created. MileageStart & MileageEnd are not compared with anything. Leaving the query like so, pretty much resolved the issue.

```
--First Stored Procedure--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetMileageBalance 
 IS  --Code declaration section--
    --variables to store column values returned from select into
     fPassengerID        VARCHAR2(10);
     pFirst              VARCHAR2(20);
     pLast               VARCHAR2(20);
     fFreqflyernum       NUMBER (10);
     fFreqflyerMileage   NUMBER (7);
     fMileagebalance     NUMBER (7);
     fMileageExpDate     DATE;
     MileageExpDate      DATE;
     MileageStart        NUMBER (7);
     MileageEnd          NUMBER (7);
     MileageBalance      NUMBER (7);

        BEGIN --Code execution section
          --executing select into Query assign to variable
          --MileageExpDate := '01/OCT/2017';--
          --MileageStart := 10000;--
          --MileageEnd :=  20000;--
         SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM,  
         F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
         INTO  fPassengerID,   
 pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage,fMileagebalance,fMileageExpDate
FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
WHERE F.MileageBalance >= 10000 AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= 20000
AND MileageExpDate > '01/OCT/2017';

--Displaying the results
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CUSTOMER INFORMATION: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  ' ||fPassengerID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('First Name of passenger is:  ' ||pFirst);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Last Name of passenger is:  ' ||pLast);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: ' ||fFreqflyernum);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  ' ||fFreqflyerMileage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageBalance );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageExpDate);

END sp_GetMileageBalance;
```

RESULTS:

```
CUSTOMER INFORMATION: 
The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  KL87DF34DS
First Name of passenger is:  Michelle
Last Name of passenger is:  Mullington
Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: 9374392018
Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  400
Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  15000
Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  19-DEC-20


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

From your proc:
AND MileageExpDate > MileageExpDate;

Do you see it?

Change your variable name to distinguish it from the column name or prefix your variable name with your procedure name. Something like the following: 
MileageExpDate > sp_GetMileageBalance.MileageExpDate

Detailed explanation here: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS017)

Comment: I've figured out what the issue is. I've explained the reasoning behind the error was ,below this page. If my error related to an ambiguous identifier issue, then my guess is that distinguishing the variable name for the sake of the complier can only circumvent the issue (if I'm correct). I should have declared fMileageExpDate to be equal to that specific date (01-OCT-17). It would work because fMileageExpDate can be compared to the attribute "F.MILEAGEEXPDATE", in which it will be able to extract the correct information from the desired tables.